# How to dynamically access r matrix row names without explicitly calling the names?

Tags: r, r-caret, flexibility

A few weeks ago I asked a question on how to extract certain rows from a matrix based on known criteria ([How to extract rows with similar names into a submatrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68821483/how-to-extract-rows-with-similar-names-into-a-submatrix)). The answers received worked phenomenally for the application at the time, but I find myself needing functionality to dynamically sample the row names and build the subsequent matrices without having to explicitly determine which name to extract.

For example, the model I built in the previous question has 6 row "families": Intercept, actsBreaks, tBreaks, etc. which could be replaced with 15+ other potential predictor variables. Changing the row construction sections by hand is cumbersome and something I need to avoid.

I messed around with `readline(prompt=...)` to have the user define which predictor variable family they wish to use, but was told this is a program the user needs to be able to loop overnight and walk away from, so no luck there. Is it possible to modify this code

```
uniBreakLines1 <- grep("actsBreaks[0-9]*", rows)
actsBreaks <- matrix1[uniBreakLines1,drop = FALSE]
```

to sample from the matrix row name vector without specifying exactly which "family" to use? Or should I use something else? The Caret Package looks promising but I am not well versed in r syntax and I am not sure if using something that claims to be primarily for machine learning would have this functionality. The answer in this question ([Subsetting a matrix by row.names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670541/subsetting-a-matrix-by-row-names)) utilizing the matrix indexing could have potential, but then we run into having to change the submatrix code by hand again.

TlDr: I need a way to filter rows by names from the matrix without typing out

```
uniBreakLines1 <- grep("actsBreaks[0-9]*", rows)
actsBreaks <- matrix1[uniBreakLines1,drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Did my answer worked here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68821483/how-to-extract-rows-with-similar-names-into-a-submatrix> ?

Comment: @TarJae yes, but it still has that explicit row name call with `df1 <- df %>% 
    filter(!str_detect(rownames(df), "unitBreaks")) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but this will return a list of matrices, one for each category (I think):

```r
res <- list()
brkcats <- unique(gsub("[0-9]*", "", rows))
for (bc in brkcats) {
      BreakLines <- grep(paste0(bc,"[0-9]*"), rows)
      res[[bc]] <- matrix1[BreakLines, , drop = FALSE]
}
```

Comment: let me edit the question to improve comprehensibility. Also, this works very well!